# entity is not currently supported by force:recordData

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, force-recorddata

I have two lightning components on a product detail object page within my community. These two components have the standard force:recordData stuff in them:

```
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  layoutType="FULL"
  targetRecord="{!v.record}"
  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
  recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
  />
```

The issue that I'm running in to is that on mobile, and only on mobile (even simulated within Chrome's mobile inspector) the record doesn't load and I get the error **This entity is not currently supported by force:recordData.** If I'm viewing these on desktop it works just fine. Furthermore, looking at the list of supported entities, **Product2** is one of them. I'm guessing that I'm missing something super simple here but not quite sure where to start looking how to go about fixing this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per salesforce documentation, Lightning Data Service is not supported on mobile.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm "Lightning Data Service is only available in Lightning Experience and the Salesforce app." <-- Salesforce app means mobile.

Comment: Bhawna, when you refer to the documentation when posting an answer, it's always best to provide a link to the documentation that you're referring to. It appears that @CharlesT has provided a link to documentation that disputes your answer.

Comment: @crmprogdev Agreed!